# How is my data stored in R?

Tags: r

So, I'm trying to figure out a larger problem, and I think it may stem from exactly what's happening when I import data from a `.txt` file. My regular beginning commands are:

```
data<-read.table("mydata.txt",header=T)
attach(data)
```

So if my data has say, 3 columns with headers `"Var1"`, `"Var2"` and `"Var3"`, how exactly is everything imported? It seems as though it is imported as 3 separate vectors, then bound together, similar to using `cbind()`.

My larger issue is modifying the data. If a row in my data frame has an empty spot (in any column) I need to remove it:

```
data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
```

Perfect - now say that the original data frame had 100 rows, 5 of which had an empty slot. My new data frame should have 95 rows, right? Well if I try:

```
> length(Var1)
[1] 100
> length(data$Var1)
[1] 95
```

So it seems like the original column labelled `Var1` is unaffected by the line where I rewrote the entire data frame. This is why I believe that when I import the data, I really just have 3 separate columns stored somewhere called `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3`. As far as getting R to recognize that I want the modified version of the column, I think I need to do something along the lines of:

```
Var1 <- data$Var1 #Repeat for every variable
```

My issue with this is that I will need to write the above bit of code for every single variable. The data frame I have is large, and this way of coding seems tedious. Is there a better way for me to transform my data, then be able to call the modified variables, without needing to use the data$ precursor every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`read.table()` reads the data into a data frame with a component (column) for each column (variable) in the text file. R's data frame is like an Excel spreadsheet, each column in the sheet can contain a different type of data (contrast that with a matrix, which in R can contain data only of a single type).

In effect, the result is as if the data were read in column by column and then bound together column-wise using the `cbind.data.frame()` method. This is not how it is done in practice though. You have a single object `data` with three components, none of which can be accessed by typing their name (e.g. `Var1`). Try *exactly* this

```
data <- read.table("mydata.txt", header = TRUE)
Var1
```

in a clean session (best if you start a new session to try this, just in case).

If you were to type `ls()` you would see only `data` listed (assuming a clean session). This is clearl evidence *against* your thinking that you have three columns and individual objects.

The real problem here is `attach()` not `read.table()`.

There are very few good uses of `attach()` and the one you show is not among them. `attach(data)` places a **copy** of `data` on the search path. The key point there is **copy**. What is on the search path is not the same thing as `data` in the global environment (your workspace). Any changes to the `data` in the global environment are not reflected in the copy on the search path, because these are two, completely separate objects.

R has a search path where it looks for named objects. Normally R doesn't look inside objects and hence `Var1` etc will not be found whenever you type their name at the prompt or attempt to use the object directly. When you `attach()` an object you can think of this as opening the object up to R's search. But the thing that catches people out is that one is now looking inside a copy of the object and not the object itself.

In interactive sessions, there are useful helper functions that mean you don't need to be typing `data$` all the time. See `?with`, `?within`, `?transform` for example.

Really don't use `attach()` in lieu of a bit of typing.

Comment: +1, that's a nice way of explaining it. I actually just put something like that in a comment using an analogy of a hardcopy vs a `.doc` file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure R reads files *row* by *row*.  (In fact, I think just about all programming languages work this way.)  I wonder if you are attaching your data frame *before* removing the incomplete cases.  The behavior you describe is fairly typical when people call `attach(data)` beforehand.  In general, it is recommended that you do not use `attach()` at all in R.  But if you must use it, call `detach(data)` *first*, then modify the data frame, and then (if you *must*) call `attach(data)` again.  At that point, you will no longer have this problem.

*Note, it is also possible that your problem is something different.  However, we cannot tell, based on the information provided thus far.  You will want to provide a reproducible example so that people can help you more effectively, see here: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/).*

Comment: "Do not use `attach()`" just about sums it up.

Comment: Ok, I tried deleted my attach() line, but the problem persists. I've read a good article about not using attach() and instead using data=my.data as an argument to avoid using my.data$Var1. When I learned R in my biostats course they always used attach(), so now I know better!

And about making reproducible code - I did try my very best, but I can't figure out how to produce a data frame in r from scratch.  I will explain in a 2nd comment.

Comment: I tried:

    `x<-c(1,2,3)
    y<-c(4,5,6)
    data<-data.frame(x,y)`

I can call x or data$x. If I `remove(x)` I can only then call `data$x` (calling `x` returns an error:object not found). Whereas if I import some data (like my original post) I can always just call `Var1` (no need to specify `data$Var1`). I think this is a symptom of me not understanding what happens when a .txt is imported.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, @darcy.mulder. I'm aware that courses often teach the `attach()` command. It can be useful, but it's also dangerous; it often trips people up, which is what I think happened to you. As far as deleting your `attach()` line, that wouldn't help if you've already run it. Try using the `detach()` etc. strategy I outline.

Comment: I cleared my workspace (using RStudio), ran the `detach()` code, and now I cannot simply call `Var1`. So now I understand what `attach()` does - it allows me to call columns of attached data frames. So if I don't attach my data, I cannot directly call `Var1`, but I need to specify `data$Var1`. I suspect this is why I was taught to use `attach()`.

Comment: That's exactly right, @darcy.mulder. `attach()` attaches a *copy* of your variables to the search path. Think of printing out a word document that you are working on & putting it on your desk. You can change the `.doc` file, but the hardcopy on your desk *does not change*.

Comment: I think working through this thread has cleared up some confusion about what's going on when I import data. So, is it standard practice to write functions in the form `mean(Var1, data=my.data)` if I wish to avoid the use of `my.data$Var1`?

Comment: As @Gavin Simpson notes, you can use `with()`, or other options, eg, depending on your situation.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me...I learned a bunch of lines of code for my course, but not the inner workings of what I was doing. I'm trying to relearn from scratch so I can code more efficiently.

Comment: Your welcome, @darcy.mulder. Learning to program by yourself in R isn't easy. You may want to get a good book and work through it. I think there's a question on that topic around here (or on SO) somewhere.

Comment: I've actually been coding for a few years now, but it was pretty patchwork. When I'm writing nested for loops and subsetting data, I  know I'm doing something more complicated than need be. So I figured I'd just start back at the beginning and ensure I understood exactly what was going on at each step.

Comment: Here is such a question on SO, if you're still interested: [how-to-learn-r-as-a-programming-language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744861/).