# Why can't this R call object in an expression be evaluated? (subsetting vs extracting from a call object)

Tags: r, object, expression

I am trying to understand the R `expression` object, but encountered some difficulties.

Code snippet:

```
a = 1
b = 2
x = expression(sin(a+b+1))
print(class(x[[1]][2]))
eval(x[[1]][2])
```

Results:

```
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////
x = expression(sin(a+b+1))
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////
print(class(x[[1]][2]))
[1] "call"
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////
x = expression(sin(a+b+1))
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////
print(class(x[[1]][2]))
[1] "call"
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////
eval(x[[1]][2])
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function
2: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
1: eval(x[[1]][2])
```

`x[[1]][2]` is a `call` object, but why can't it be evaluated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the `[[` operator, and not the `[`.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
eval(x[[1]][[2]])
## [1] 4
```

This is because you'd like to extract information from the language object, and not to subset it (look inside the 2nd element, and not return a subsequence consisting of the 2nd element).

In other words, subsetting a `call` gives you a `call`:

```
x[[1]][2]
## (a + b + 1)()
```

and because there is no such function as `a+b+1` (in fact, the result of `a+b+1`'s evaluation is not a function object), R throws an error.

Interestingly, if `+` would return a function object, this could make sense:

```
"+" <- function(a, b) { function() print(":-)") }
(a+b+1)()
[1] ":-)"
```

On the other hand, extracting an element from a call object gives you an expression that can be evaluated:

```
x[[1]][[2]]
a + b + 1
```

(BTW, this expression is also a call, here equivalent to `"+"(a, "+"(b, 1))`.

**EDIT**. More formally, a call is an expression  (sequence) of the form:

```
(f, a1, ..., an),
```

which we normally read as:

```
f(a1, ..., an).
```

Thus, the first element of the sequence is an object used to transform the other elements to get an output value.

Here `x[[1]]` is equivalent to:

```
(sin, a+b+1)
```

or, in more detail,

```
(sin, (+, a, (+, b, 1))).
```

Thus, `x[[1]][2]` takes a subsequence of the above consisting of only the 2nd element and returns:

```
((+, a, (+, b, 1)))
```

(i.e. `(a+b+1)()` - no args!). On the other hand `x[[1]][[2]]` extracts (looks inside) the 2nd element and gives:

(+, a, (+, b, 1)),

i.e. `a+b+1` (note one pair of parentheses less).

**EDIT2**: All of this exemplifies the beauty and expressiveness of the R language, at least IMHO. Let's study another example in which we create a call `f1(f2(f3, f4), f3, f4)`,
which may be represented by a sequence

```
(f1, (f2, f3, f4), f3, f4).
```

We have:

```
f <- function(...) invisible(NULL)
f1 <- f; f2 <- f; f3 <- f; f4 <- f # for sake of clarity below
expr <- quote(f1(f2(f3, f4), f3, f4))
print(expr)
## f1(f2(f3, f4), f3, f4),           i.e. (f1, (f2, f3, f4), f3, f4)
print(expr[1:3])
## f1(f2(f3, f4), f3),               i.e. (f1, (f2, f3, f4), f3)
print(expr[3:4])
## f3(f4),                           i.e. (f3, f4)
print(expr[3])
## f3(),                             i.e. (f3)
expr[2]
## f2(f3, f4)(),                     i.e. ((f2, f3, f4)) [subsetting!]
```

And now for something completely different:

```
expr[[2]]
## f2(f3, f4),                       i.e. (f2, f3, f4) [extraction]
```

Hope this clarifies these issues a little bit.

Comment: Both class(x[[1]][[2]]) and class(x[[1]][2]) are calls.

Comment: One gives you a call to `(a+b+1)()` and the other one to `"+"(a, "+"(b, 1))`.

Comment: I've made some edits, hope it clarifies more of this complicated topic. :)

Comment: And more edits (BTW, [this book](http://rksiazka.rexamine.com/) explains this topic in very detail, unfortunately it's in Polish...)

Comment: Oh, I would like to give you 10 upvotes! Is the book freely available?

Comment: Unfortunately, the publisher does not allow its sharing. :(

Comment: I have a Polish colleague in the office!

Comment: Is there a similar book in English?

Comment: Try with Chamber's books, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744861/how-to-learn-r-as-a-programming-language

Comment: Another indicator of the difference: ≤n>h(x[[1]][2])length(x[[1]][2]) is 11 while ≤n>h(x[[1]][[2]])length(x[[1]][[2]]) is 33 .  Annoyingly enough, tho'  both `eval(x[1])` and `eval(x[[1]])` yield the desired calculation.

Comment: This also makes sense for me: you can evaluate an expression (containing for example multiple calls == a sequence of calls) like `x[1]` or a single call like `x[[1]]`...