# Does R Cookbook work with Rstudio?

Tags: r

This is a very basic question, but since I am new to R and I am starting to learn it now, I am buying this book.

```
http://www.amazon.in/Cookbook-OReilly-Cookbooks-Paul-Teetor/dp/0596809158
```

Now, after reading the sampler available on the internet, I found out that all the examples are given in R but I use Rstudio. I just wanted to know that the same instructions and syntax will work in Rstudio as well, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Rstudio is the IDE. Simple answer is: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically - yes. RStudio is (only) the IDE (Integrated development environment - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for R.

Hovewer, R Cookbook is from 2011, so it's recipes depend on quite old R version. It's possible, that some of recipes won't work, not because of using RStudio, but because of using newer R version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, should I use some other book? Can you suggest something else? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you're looking for. Do you want some introduction to R book?

Comment: Yes,from beginning to a certainly high level.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744861/how-to-learn-r-as-a-programming-language and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25632/what-book-is-recommendable-to-start-learning-statistics-using-r-at-the-same-time