# How to use tapply from within a for loop

Tags: r

I have a data.frame "df" which has 200 observations and 18 columns.
The 18 columns are var1, var2, etc....
When I use:

```
tapply(df$var1, INDEX=df$varX, FUN=mean, na.rm=T)
```

where varX is a fixed value of a certain variable (var) of type string, I get the mean of var1 for each value of varX. 
my question is:
How may I put the above command in a for loop such that it would iterate the same command such that it will cover all variables (var1, var2, ...etc) except of course varX?
I tried this:

```
for (k in c(var1, var2, ..., varn)) {
tapply(df$k, INDEX=df$varX, FUN=mean, na.rm=T)
}
```

But it did not work.

Please note:
I am sure much more effective and elegant methods/scripts can be used, but since I am a beginner, and so much behind, I sometimes try to go ahead and apply some ideas before I finish reading the respective chapter of a book I have. This is why my method(s) sometimes look primitive.

Comment: Don't do this. Either use `aggregate(. ~ varX, df, mean, na.rm = TRUE)` or `summarise_each` from `dplyr` or `lapply(.SD, mean)` within the `data.table` frame work.

Comment: is `df$varX` a character variable?

Comment: You cannot use "$" with variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079415/define-right-parameter-with-a-variable-in-r

Comment: @vpipkt: Yes, df$varX is a character variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct adaptation of what you are looking for (using `iris` as the example data frame) is:

```
for(k in iris[-5])   # we loop through the columns in `iris`, except last
  print(tapply(k, INDEX=iris$Species, FUN=mean, na.rm=T))
```

Which produces:

```
setosa versicolor  virginica 
 5.006      5.936      6.588 
setosa versicolor  virginica 
 3.428      2.770      2.974 
setosa versicolor  virginica 
 1.462      4.260      5.552 
setosa versicolor  virginica 
 0.246      1.326      2.026
```

Slightly more elegantly using `sapply` instead of `for`:

```
sapply(iris[-5], tapply, INDEX=iris$Species, mean, na.rm=T)
```

which produces:

```
           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
setosa            5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
virginica         6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

But really, you want to use `aggregate`, `dplyr`, or `data.table` as others have suggested:

```
data.table(iris)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=Species]
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris, mean, na.rm = TRUE) # Courtesy David Arenburg
```

The firs two require loading the packages `data.table` and `dplyr` respectively.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.
I will continue  reading about R for sure.

Comment: Why not just `aggregate(. ~ varX, df, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg because I don't know how to use `aggregate`? =)

Comment: This one also worked:
    for(k in 4:20)
    print(tapply(df[[k]], INDEX=df$varX, FUN=mean, na.rm=T))
varX was the third variable, so it was omitted from values assumed by k.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
na.omit() %>%
group_by(varX) %>%
summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rowsum()`, which is one of the fastest base R aggregation functions (although here we'll need to divide it by the counts of the grouping variable to get the mean).

Following BrodieG's example using `data(iris)` grouped by `Species`, we can do

```
grp <- iris$Species
rowsum(iris[-5], grp, na.rm = TRUE) / tabulate(grp, nlevels(grp))
#            Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# setosa            5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
# versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
# virginica         6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```