# Select random element in a list of R?

Tags: r

```
a<-c(1,2,0,7,5)
```

Some languages have a picker -function -- choose one random number from `a` -- how in R?

Comment: On a side note: You seem like you're new to R and should probably just read some introductory materials.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420296/what-are-some-good-books-web-resources-and-projects-for-learning-r

Comment: On another side note: The example data you are providing is a vector, not a list. In case you want to know how to sample an element from a list, you may have a look here: https://statisticsglobe.com/select-random-element-from-list-in-r

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
# Sample from the vector 'a' 1 element.
sample(a, 1)
```

Comment: Be careful with sample! If `a` has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and `a` >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from `1:a`. Note that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behavior when `a` is of varying length.

Comment: Is there any function in R that sample the values and leaves unchosen values as NAs?

Comment: @hhh Only a few years late but... I don't really understand what you want with that

Answer (score 36):

the above answers are technically correct:

```
sample(a, 1)
```

however, if you would like to repeat this process many times, let's say you would like to imitate throwing a dice, then you need to add:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
sample(a, 12, replace=TRUE)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 21):

**Be careful when using sample!**

`sample(a, 1)` works great for the vector in your example, but when the vector has length 1 it may lead to undesired behavior, it will use the vector `1:a` for the sampling.

So if you are trying to pick a random item from a varying length vector, check for the case of length 1!

```
sampleWithoutSurprises <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) <= 1) {
    return(x)
  } else {
    return(sample(x,1))
  }
}
```

Comment: They should fix this bug.

Answer (score 7):

This method doesn't produce an error when your vector is length one, and it's simple.

```
a[sample(1:length(a), 1)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Read [this](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/02/how-to-choose-a-random-number-in-r.html) article about generating random numbers in R.

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/02/how-to-choose-a-random-number-in-r.html

You can use `sample` in this case

```
sample(a, 1)
```

Second attribute is showing that you want to get only **one** random number.
To generate number between some range `runif` function is useful.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to select an item from the vector using runif. i.e

```
a <- c(1,2,0,7,5)
a[runif(1,1,6)]
```

Lets say you want a function that picks one each time it is run (useful in a simulation for example). So

```
a <- c(1,2,0,7,5)
sample_fun_a <- function() sample(a, 1)
runif_fun_a <- function() a[runif(1,1,6)]
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sample_fun_a(), 
                           runif_fun_a(),
                           times = 100000L)
```

Unit: nanoseconds

sample_fun_a() - 4665

runif_fun_a() - 1400

runif seems to be quicker in this example.