# Random sampling with replace = FALSE, results in duplicates being selected using R

Tags: r, frame, sampling

I have a requirement where in 70 odd data needs to be separated into 7 random data frame without any duplicate rows being selected, i.e. Replace = FALSE has been used still it picks duplicate rows
even with sample_n() function results are the same.

Is it a bug known?

How will this be remedied as for future requirements this makes and arduous job to manually select.

df = name = c("arjun","Andrea", "Biswas","Ann","Biju", "Sheela","Deepti","Betty", "Hema", "Gowri"," Kunal", "Anamika","Ashik", "Hina","Kiran"
)

gender = c("M","F", "M","M","F", "M","F","F","F", "F","M","F", "F","F","M")

etc like wise 5 with additional columns
each group needs two females and rest males.
but the basic splitting itself is having duplicates generated in group
say arjun is in group 1 and 3
Andrea is in group 2 and 3 etc which should not happen.

code i tried

```
library(dplyr)
L4 = list()
dfc = list()
f = list()

numzone <- c(1:5)

for (i in numzone){

L4  <-  df[sample(nrow(df) ,size = 3 ,replace = FALSE),]




f<-paste("df", i, sep="")

dfc <- L4



if (i %in% c(1:5)) {

f <- dfc[]
}



print(f)
```

Also, additionally I need this separated rows be assigned to dynamic data frame, may be from a list defined.

Comment: thanks for the update I tried to run but pool is giving error, no pool defined

Comment: `Error in dfn : object 'dfn' not found`

Comment: dfn be replaced with df and include some more data in multiple of 7 say around 14, 28, say df = name = c("arjun","Andrea", "Biswas"
"alok","Ajay", "Biinus"
)

gender = c("M","F", "M")

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145863/splitting-a-data-frame-into-equal-parts

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you found a bug, but it is hard to say without example data and the code you are using. I'd wager that you are running `sample()` (or whatever similar function) more than once, which even if you used `replace=FALSE`, could return the same value multiple times. In other words, `replace=FALSE` is only going to affect each call of `sample()`.

If you'd like more specific advice, feel free to edit your question with an example dataset and the code you are using.

Here is a general approach to this problem. More information on sampling, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390965/select-random-element-in-a-list-of-r), and more information on splitting, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks).

```
# values to be randomly sampled
pool <- 1:70

# dataframe to receive random samples
dat <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 0))

# take random samples, split into  7 groups
split(sample(x = pool, size = 70, replace = FALSE), f = ceiling(seq_along(pool)/10))

# rbind to other data
rbind(dat, split(sample(x = pool, size = 70, replace = FALSE), f = ceiling(seq_along(pool)/10)))
```